# Add columns headers to a Report Viewer with blank areas

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, report-viewer2010

We have a sign off sheet that will be printed.

it's format is something like:

```
  Room - Conference 1     Monday          Tuesday       Wednesday
                         AM  |  PM       AM  |  PM     AM  |  PM
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Bob Smith             |    |       |       |       |     |        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Terry Jones           |    |       |       |       |     |        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Jill Smith            |    |       |       |       |     |        |
```

Now, I have an RDLC that emits a page for each Room name along with the people.

What I'm trying to do is add the "monday", and AM/PM areas.  When I drop a "table" onto that area of the report and set the headers it replicates the "am/pm" rows once for each person... like the following:

```
  Room - Conference 1     Monday          Tuesday       Wednesday
                         AM  |  PM       AM  |  PM     AM  |  PM
                         AM  |  PM       AM  |  PM     AM  |  PM
                         AM  |  PM       AM  |  PM     AM  |  PM
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Bob Smith             |    |       |       |       |     |        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Terry Jones           |    |       |       |       |     |        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Jill Smith            |    |       |       |       |     |        |
```

I tried removing the dataset association on the table, but studio won't let me do that.  Also I thought about splitting out those columns into multiple other columns, but I can't do that either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out that I just need to right click on a column in the outermost group and say Add Column 10 times.. Then select the top most row and say "merge cells", then on each. individual. cell. I had to set the border properties.

Lovely. but it works.